# Missing SQL Server Registry Entry for Instance Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When developing a project on SQL Server, I accidentally deleted the value here. And the system does not turn on.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Program Files** you will have a folder called **Microsoft SQL Server**. Your instance name is the next folder you see. In my case (SQL Developer Edition) it is as below.

[image]

[image]